# Get the data from a column in a selected row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have `listView` with following columns Name & Email with following data like

```
NAME     EMAIL
adam     adam@gmail.com
james    james@gmail.com
kris     kris@gmail.com
```

I select james row, now on two textboxes I want their name & email to be there
like

```
textbox1 = james
textbox2 = james@gmail.com
```

What I'm doing actually is on `form1` I've `contextmenu` with item update.
on the click of `updatecontextmenu` ill load `form2` with `textbox` name and email.
`listview` contains name and email as shown above.

I want to place the name from the selected row from the list view to name `textbox` and email respectively.

I tried this.

```
updateToolStripMenuItem_Click(...)
{

    Form3 update = new Form3();
    update.ShowDialog();            
}

Form3_Load(...)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    string oldName = f1.listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
    string oldEmail = f1.listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
    textBox1.Text = oldName.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = oldEmail.ToString();
}
```

but getting error.

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'
im getting this error so i asked mofo.

Comment: Please show some code you wrote which throws the error. what is mofo for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update.
Try add to your `Form3` window method:

```
public void SetData(string name, string email)
{
    textBox1.Text = name;
    textBox2.Text = email;
}
```

next, update your `updateToolStripMenuItem_Click` event handler to:

```
updateToolStripMenuItem_Click(...)
{
    Form3 update = new Form3();
    ListViewItem selectedItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    update.SetData(selectedItem.SubItems[0].Text, selectedItem.SubItems[1].Text);
    update.ShowDialog();            
}
```

finally, clear content of `Form3_Load(...)`

Comment: Thanks alot pal.
i really appreciate it.
God Bless You.

Comment: In Form3_Load event handler you created new instance of Form1 and in that instance was no selected item.

Comment: oh ok i got it.
so listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text is meaning less in form3 because item was selected in form1 but not in form2
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
ListViewItem selItem = ListView1.SelectedItems[0];
Console.WriteLine(selItem.SubItems[0].Text);
Console.WriteLine(selItem.SubItems[1].Text);
```

Comment: still getting error.
what im doing actually is.
on form1 ive contextmenu with item update.
on the click of updatecontextmenu ill load form2 with textbox name and email.
listview contains name and email as shown above.
i want to place the name from the selected row from the list view to name textbox and email respecively.

i tried this.

        private void updateToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form3 update = new Form3();
            update.ShowDialog();            
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a properties from your `Form3`

```
public string OldName {get;set;}
public string OldEmail {get;set;}
```

Then, from your `From1`

```
updateToolStripMenuItem_Click(...)
{
    using(var update = new Form3())
    {
        var firstCol = listView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        update.OldName = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        update.OldEmail = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
        update.ShowDialog();     
    } 
}
```

Then, in `Form3` looks like this

```
Form3_Load(...)
{
    textBox1.Text = OldName;
    textBox2.Text = OldEmail;
}
```